# connect() failed (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream Nginx Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, nginx

We have a setup of nginx (nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)) talking to tomcat server (7.0.39) on ubuntu (5 tomcat instances on the same physical server), Everything works fine till we get 15000 requests / minute, We start facing issue Whenever we get greater than @ 20000 - 25000 req/minute suddenly for couple of seconds on the nginx   server, the nginx error logs get " connect() failed (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream ".

We have observed that the error in nginx error logs are for all the 5 tomcat instances at one go and not for only one of them - so that raises a question if there is a limit reached suddenly for sockets, or open files or something else at server level?

```
#########
 ulimit -a  
core file size              (blocks, -c) 0  
data seg size               (kbytes, -d) unlimited  
scheduling priority                 (-e) 0  
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited  
pending signals                 (-i) 32063  
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64  
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited  
open files                      (-n) 65536  
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8  
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200  
real-time priority              (-r) 0   
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192  
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited  
max user processes              (-u) 32063  
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited  
file locks                      (-x) unlimited  

#########
```

I would like to know if there are any settings on

1. Sockets or File handles thats limiting the nginx or tomcat servers. We have already changed the permanent settings in limits.conf as shown above.
2. Is there any network settings that limits the number of concurrent requests from nginx server to tomcat server?
3. The tomcat server.xml has been configured with following parameters - maxThreads="500" minSpareThreads="150" acceptCount="250" acceptorThreadCount="2"
4. We have enough idle DB connections so that does not seem to be the issue. Tomcat does not go to DB for all requests
5. Most of the threads in tomcat are in following state

   "http-bio-8181-exec-8" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f38b8006800 nid=0x590e waiting on condition [0x00007f39490ac000] java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)     at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)parking to wait for  <0x00000007811f9908> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
6. Nginx settings are as follows:
           #############

   ```
           worker_processes 4;
           pid /run/nginx.pid;
           worker_rlimit_nofile 16384;

           events {
                   worker_connections 10000;
                   # multi_accept on;
           }

           http {

                   proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
                   proxy_send_timeout   600s;
                   proxy_read_timeout   600s;
                   send_timeout 600s;

       #############
   ```

Comment: Strangely when I do a netstat check on my tomcat server on a particular instance port, I see only 1 or 2 established connection wherever incoming requests are continuously or order 15K to 20K per minute.# netstat -tan |grep :8181|awk '{print $6}'|sort | uniq -c
      1 ESTABLISHED
      1 LISTEN
      1 SYN_RECV

Comment: After posting here now increasing the settings in tomcat server.xml to maxThreads="750" minSpareThreads="500" to check if that helps.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue? We have exactly the same problem.

Comment: Following things helped us resolve the issue especially the first two:

 - Adjusting tcp_fin_timeout - [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/23385/huge-amount-of-time-wait-connections-says-netstat)
 - Increasing the port range - [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-increase-outgoing-network-sockets-range.html)
 - Added more nginx servers in the front after the node balancer that helped reducing the incoming requests on one nginx server.